# I can not access my Container Docker Image by HTTP

Tags: docker, google-kubernetes-engine

I created an image with apache2 running locally on a docker container via Dockerfile exposing port 80. Then pushed to my DockerHUB repository

I created a new instance of Container Engine In my project on the Google Cloud. Within this I have two clusters, the **Master** and the **Node1**.
Then created a Pod specifying the name of my image in DockerHUB and configuring Ports **"containerPort"** and **"hostPort"** for **6379** and **80** respectively.

Node1 accessed via SSH and the command line: `$ sudo docker ps -l` Then I found that my docker container there is.
I created a service for instance by configuring the ports as in the Pod, **"containerPort"** and **"hostPort"** for **6379** and **80** respectively.
I checked the Firewall is available with access to port 80. Even without deems it necessary, I created a rule to allow access through port 6379.

But when I enter `http://IP_ADDRESS:PORT` is not available.
Any idea about what it's wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify what IP Address you are using? Is it the IP address of the master node or of node1?

Comment: Your use case seems very similar to the 'Hello Wordpress' getting started example (https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/hello-wordpress) have you tried running through that to see if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a service to access your pod, you should configure the service to use an external load balancer (similarly to what is done in the guestbook example's [frontend service definition](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/guestbook/frontend-service.json)) and you should not need to specify a host port in your pod definition.

Once you have an external load balancer created, then you should open a firewall rule to allow external access to the load balancer which will allow packets to reach the service (and pods backing it) running in your cluster.